# How do I get data from a url callback

Tags: python, url, callback

I am using a web service that will send a url callback when a particular external event happens (that service is monitoring it 24-7)

I need to have a python script running (locally on my own computer) and waiting (possibly just looping) to receive that callback and then do something with the data.

How do I do this? Do I need to have a webserver running? Where do I look for the data? I am pretty experienced with python, but not much in the use of HTTP and other web related things.

I have looked at other stackoverflow posts but they all seem to presume some prior knowledge.... I need the basics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple server using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/) Microframework .

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, route, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/listener')
def my_listener():
    data = request.query.your_data
    #do_something_with_data(data)
    return data

run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

You can send data to server requesting **http://sever_ip:8080/listener?your_data=some_data**

Comment: Fantastic! I knew that the answer must be simple. Will that run in the background in a different process, or do I need to run the 'my_listener' periodically from my mainline code?

Comment: it will run in the background and listen for port 8080 until you stop the process

Answer (score 0):

Look into setting up a [Flask server](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that will run in the background and listen for the callback request